# How to unzip files present inside another zip file in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net-2010

I have a folder containing zip files. I want to unzip them. After unzipping them, I have to find if there are any other zip file found inside the directory. If found, I've to unzip them also. The inner level of the presence of zip files are undetermined. How to unzip all the zip files in sub directories.

Comment: What library do you use  to unzip the zip-files?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a fundamentally recursive operation. As Tim indicated above, we can't really give specifics without knowing the library you're using (personally, I'm a fan of Ionic's library), but it would go something like this:

```
Function Unzip(file as File)
  zipfile = ZipLibrary.Load(file);
  For Each innerfile as File in zipfile.files
    If (innerfile.Name.EndsWith(".zip")) Then
      Unzip(innerfile);
    End If
  End For
End Function
```

Of course, as with any form of recursion like this, you can potentially save on stack space by building a list of files to be unpacked and adding and iterating through it rather than doing the recursive call. You could also potentially use the zip library itself to check whether a file is a valid zip file if you are uncertain whether it will have the correct extension.